# Setting header image using Paypal Adaptive Payments

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I was hoping to set a header image on a **Paypal Chained Payment** in a similar way to an **Express Checkout** using the **API**. To achieve this with the Express Checkout you just set a URL on HDRIMG eg. https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/api/setexpresscheckout-api-operation-nvp

However I couldn't find any reference to do something similar using the Adaptive Payments API. https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/api/pay-api-operation

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the SetPaymentOptions API Operation.

Here is the link: https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_APSetPaymentOptions